# How to create Jitsi unique room?

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am facing problems to create a unique room for Jitsi Meeting.

Here is how I am creating it, using their documentation:

```
const domain = 'live.exmaple.com';
const options = {
    roomName: '{{ $case->uuid }}',
    width: 700,
    height: 400,
    jwt: '{{ $case->token() }}',
    parentNode: document.querySelector('#meet'),
    moderator: true
};
const api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, options);
```

The jitsi service is already installed on live.exmaple.com and is working fine, but on domain.com, when I try to create a room with authorized access it fails.

By checking the console, I found the following errors:

- 404 - the unique room cannot be found, because it doesn't create it.
- Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://exmaple.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Is it a problem that the service is installed on a subdomain and I am calling it from the domain?
How can i fix this Cross-origin issue and will it help me to create the room?